# Contentful Product Catalogue Error

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-studio, contentful

I have download this CONTENTFUL CMS product catalogue demo ->https://github.com/contentful/product-catalogue-android. Im using android studio 1.4. 
I have set the public token ID in the const.java accordingly but it still get error. At first i think maybe i have set a wrong setting at content_type field setting. But i still cannot find my solution. My error look like below and ive attached images for you to see,

```
10-23 18:56:18.820 2094-2147/catalogue.contentful E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: entry_nulundg0rwhzuvm0suntyxvdzufjrq
 (1) no such table: entry_ne90ogm2rdjxuxfnb2fvs2dzbtgysw
```

This is my JSON statement from my CONTENTFUL "Product": content_type

```
{
  "name": "Product",
  "description": "",
  "displayField": "productName",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "productName",
      "id": "productName",
      "type": "Symbol",
      "localized": false,
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "productDescription",
      "id": "productDescription",
      "type": "Symbol",
      "localized": false,
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "sizetypecolor",
      "id": "sizetypecolor",
      "type": "Symbol"
    },
    {
      "name": "images",
      "id": "images",
      "type": "Array",
      "items": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Asset",
        "validations": []
      },
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "categories",
      "id": "categories",
      "type": "Link",
      "linkType": "Entry",
      "validations": [
        {
          "linkContentType": [
            "5In484EhYQS4ICSauCeAcE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "tags",
      "id": "tags",
      "type": "Array",
      "items": {
        "type": "Symbol",
        "validations": []
      },
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "price",
      "id": "price",
      "type": "Number",
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "brand",
      "id": "brand",
      "type": "Link",
      "linkType": "Entry",
      "validations": [
        {
          "linkContentType": [
            "5gTQW9EcAwEYEc42WGgaEu"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "quantity",
      "id": "quantity",
      "type": "Integer",
      "localized": false,
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "sku",
      "id": "sku",
      "type": "Symbol",
      "localized": false,
      "validations": []
    },
    {
      "name": "website",
      "id": "website",
      "type": "Symbol",
      "localized": false,
      "validations": []
    }
  ],
  "sys": {
    "id": "4Ot8c6D2qQqgoaUKgYm82K",
    "type": "ContentType",
    "createdAt": "2015-10-23T13:04:54.705Z",
    "createdBy": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "User",
        "id": "2P70I7YlhYLnC0iOpPYYwN"
      }
    },
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "b7di2z8ukacn"
      }
    },
    "firstPublishedAt": "2015-10-23T13:04:59.904Z",
    "publishedCounter": 17,
    "publishedAt": "2015-10-23T17:33:41.088Z",
    "publishedBy": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "User",
        "id": "2P70I7YlhYLnC0iOpPYYwN"
      }
    },
    "publishedVersion": 41,
    "version": 42,
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-23T17:33:41.107Z",
    "updatedBy": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "User",
        "id": "2P70I7YlhYLnC0iOpPYYwN"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my Android Studio coding

```
  public Product$$ModelHelper() {
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("productName").setName("name").setSqliteType("STRING").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("productDescription").setName("description").setSqliteType("STRING").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("sizetypecolor").setName("sizeTypeColor").setSqliteType("STRING").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("image").setName("images").setArrayType("com.contentful.vault.Asset").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("tags").setName("tags").setSqliteType("BLOB").setArrayType("java.lang.String").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("categories").setName("categories").setArrayType("catalogue.contentful.vault.Category").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("price").setName("price").setSqliteType("DOUBLE").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("brand").setName("brand").setLinkType("ENTRY").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("quantity").setName("quantity").setSqliteType("INT").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("sku").setName("sku").setSqliteType("STRING").build());
    fields.add(FieldMeta.builder().setId("website").setName("website").setSqliteType("STRING").build());
  }

  @Override
  public List<FieldMeta> getFields() {
    return fields;
  }

  @Override
  public String getTableName() {
    return "entry_ne90ogm2rdjxuxfnb2fvs2dzbtgysw";
  }
```

[My Android Studio project error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV6Al.jpg)

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem.Because this app is a demo, i really think my problem is at my setting at CONTENTFUL, but maybe i need second opinion. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Your image link is broken, needs to be reversed.

Comment: Hi Erik, ive fix the broken link...sorry....

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mario from Contentful here,

As I could see from the code you provided, it seems as if you changed the generated classes. Can you try changing the `Product.java` using the annotations provided by `vault` to create a Product matching your data?

This also needs to be done with all the other `ContentTypes`, you created in the Contentful-WebUI.